# How to derive group velocity dispersion (GVD)?

Tags: waves, frequency, wavelength, dispersion, fiber-optics

I'm trying to arrive to the following expression to [group velocity dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity_dispersion):

$$\text{GVD} = \frac{\lambda^3}{2 \pi c^2} \frac{d^2n}{d \omega^2}.$$

I know that GVD can be expressed as:

$$\text{GVD} = \frac{d}{d\omega}\left( \frac{1}{v_g} \right)$$

where

$$\frac{1}{v_g} = \frac{dk}{d\omega}
\\k = \frac{\omega}{c} n(\omega)
\\\omega = \frac{2\pi c}{\lambda}$$

and the refraction index depends on the wavelength.

How can I arrive at the first GVD expression knowing the others?

Comment: your first two equations do not match. The first one has a dimension of $L^2T^3$ and the second one of $L^{-1}T^2$.

Comment: I check and is c^2 on the first equation.

Comment: Where do you get the first equation?

Comment: The teacher provided it.

Comment: @sleepy I make the first one $\mathsf{LT}^4$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there should be a second derivative of refractive index with respect to the wavelength in the GVD definition as otherwise the values would look different.

As you have already indicated, inverse of the group velocity is defined $\frac{1}{v_{g}} = \frac{dk}{d \omega}$ and $k = \frac{\omega n(\omega)}{c}$. Therefore, we can find the value by performing the derivation with the product rule:
$$ \frac{dk}{d \omega} = \frac{1}{c} \left(n(\omega) + \frac{dn(\omega)}{d\omega} \omega \right)  = \frac{1}{v_g}\tag{1}$$

However, at the end, we want everything to be expressed in wavelength so we apply the chain rule:
$$ \frac{dn}{d\omega} = \frac{dn}{d\lambda_{0}} \frac{d\lambda_{0}}{d \omega}\tag{2}$$
We know that wavelength in the vacuum is related to the angular frequency $\lambda_{0} = \frac{2\pi c}{\omega}$ and we can find the derivative with respect to the angular frequency:
$$\frac{d\lambda_{0}}{d \omega} = \frac{-\lambda_{0}^{2}}{2\pi c} \tag{3}$$
Substituting $(3)$ into $(2)$ and then into $(1)$ we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{v_g} = \frac{1}{c} \left(  n(\lambda_{0}) - \lambda_{0} \frac{dn}{d \lambda_{0}} \right) \tag{4}$$
So now for the group velocity dispersio we have: $\mathrm{GVD}=\frac{d}{d \omega}(\frac{1}{v_{g}})$. Again, we need to apply the chain rule to obtain the correct variable:
$$ \frac{d}{d\omega} = \frac{d}{d\lambda_{0}} \frac{d\lambda_{0}}{d \omega} \tag{5}$$
Now, by having $(4)$, $(5)$ and GVD definition, we combine everything and apply the product rule:
$$ \mathrm{GVD} = \frac{d}{d \omega} \left( \frac{1}{v_{g}} \right) = \frac{-\lambda_{0}^{2}}{2\pi c} \frac{d}{d \lambda_{0}} \left[ \frac{1}{c} \left( n(\lambda_{0}) - \lambda_{0} \frac{dn(\lambda_{0})}{d\lambda_{0}}\right ) \right] = \frac{\lambda_{0}^{3}}{2\pi c^{2}} \frac{d^{2}n(\lambda_{0})}{d \lambda_{0}^{2}}$$